# Postgresql check constraint on all individual elements in array using function

Tags: arrays, postgresql

If I have a table

```
create table foo ( bar text[] not null check ..... );
```

and a function

```
create function baz(text) returns boolean as $$ .....
```

How do I add a check constraint to the foo table such that every element in the bar field validates the baz function?

I'm thinking that I need to create a function

```
create function array_baz(arg text[]) returns boolean as $$ 
    with x as ( select baz(unnest(arg)) as s_arg )
    select not exists (select 1 from x where s_arg = false)
$$ language sql strict immutable;

 create table foo (bar text[] not null check ( array_baz(bar) = true ) );
```

However, I'm sure that I'm reinventing the wheel here and there's a cuter way of doing this. What psql trick am I missing? A map function would be nice

```
create table foo (bar text[] not null check (true = all(map('baz', bar)));
```

but so far my search efforts are fruitless.

Comment: You can simplify the function to `select every(baz(u)) from unnest(arg) u`, but I can't think of any way to get rid of it entirely...

Comment: Thanks @NickBarnes . Was fairly sure there would be a nicer way of writing that CTE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do what you want in more than one way. If you want to use the `ALL(...)` quantifiers, you need a suitable *operator*. For that, you first need a function to perform what you want:

Imagine you want to check that your texts don't have any uppercase letter in them. You'd define a function like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION doesnt_have_uppercase(b boolean, t text)
/* Compares b to the result of `t` not having any non-lowercase character */
    RETURNS boolean
    IMMUTABLE
    STRICT
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT (t = lower(t)) = b
$$ ;
```

Based on it, [create an operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html):

```
CREATE OPERATOR =%= (
    PROCEDURE = doesnt_have_uppercase,
    LEFTARG = boolean,
    RIGHTARG = text
) ;
```

You need this operator because the [`ANY` and `ALL` quantifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21127) need the following structure:

```
expression operator ALL(array)
```

At this point, you can define:

```
create table foo 
( 
    bar text[] not null,
    CONSTRAINT bar_texts_cant_have_uppercase CHECK(true =%= ALL(bar))
);
```

Which will lead you to the following behaviour:

```
INSERT INTO foo
    (bar)
VALUES
    (ARRAY['this will pass', 'this too']) ;
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO foo
    (bar)
VALUES
    (ARRAY['that would pass', 'BUT THIS WILL PREVENT IT']) ;
```

```
ERROR:  new row for relation "foo" violates check constraint "bar_texts_cant_have_uppercase"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains ({"that would pass","BUT THIS WILL PREVENT IT"}).
```

Check it all at 
*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d3e7fbaee62beb455197097df3a06988)*

---

I would most probably seek a less tortuous route, however:

```
CREATE FUNCTION doesnt_have_uppercase(t text[])
/* Returns true if all elements of t don't have any uppercase letter */
    RETURNS boolean
    IMMUTABLE
    STRICT
    LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM unnest(t) q WHERE q <> lower(q)))
$$ ;

create table foo 
( 
    bar text[] not null,
    CONSTRAINT bar_texts_cant_have_uppercase CHECK(doesnt_have_uppercase(bar))
);
```

This behaves exactly like the previous example (except if some of the elements of the array are NULL).

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=bc88315af8ed96764594b417a15d0349)*

Comment: Thanks. Your last solution looks pretty much the same as what I had in the question so I'm assuming you don't know a simple built-in like a map function and instead I have to write either an operator or another function? I'll accept your answer in two weeks if nobody else answers.

Answer (score 3):

Check constraints can be applied to individual items in an array by defining a [domain type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html):

```sql
CREATE DOMAIN lower_text AS text
CHECK(
  VALUE = lower(VALUE)
);

CREATE TABLE test (
  name lower_text[] NOT NULL
);
```